# $e^z\in\mathbb R$ if and only if $z\in\mathbb R\cup{\rm i}2\pi\mathbb Z$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $z\in\mathbb C$.

> How can we show that $e^z\in\mathbb R$ if and only if $z\in\mathbb R\cup{\rm i}2\pi\mathbb Z$?

The claim is made in the proof of [Corollary 2.3.4 of *Structural Aspects In The Theory Of Probability*](https://books.google.com/books?id=cPvICgAAQBAJ&pg=PA61&lpg=PA61&dq=%22corollary+2.3.4%22+%22since+p+is+symmetric+and+hence%22&source=bl&ots=Ai4_fngKzr&sig=ACfU3U1KduF3odyy0pmUHqZmsidF5ZxA5Q&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwichdb9-ZLzAhUWh_0HHeMKBJsQ6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=%22corollary%202.3.4%22%20%22since%20p%20is%20symmetric%20and%20hence%22&f=false).

The "if"-part is trivial by rembering that $$e^{{\rm i}x}=\cos x+{\rm i}\sin x\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in\mathbb R,$$ but unless I'm missing something, we should replace ${\rm i}2\pi\mathbb Z$ by ${\rm i}\pi\mathbb Z$ (since the only thing we need to ensure is $\sin x=0$, which is precisely the case if $x\in\pi\mathbb Z$).

With this possible correction of the statement in mind, how can we show the "only if"-part?

Comment: No.  For example if $x$ is real, then $e^{x+i 2 \pi} = e^x$.

Comment: If you take $z = x + iy$, then $e^z = e^xe^{iy}$. It should be easy from here. Note that the second part of the condition should be $\Im(z) \in \pi\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @Just_a_newbie So, the "$\cup$" should be "+" and the "$2$" shouldn't be there, right? Is there anything special in the reference in the book or is that a typo?

Comment: How do you define the real number $\pi$? - this is the crunch. [I define it as the least positive zero of $\cos x$, and then can show that $\sin$ and $\cos$ are periodic of period $2\pi$, and that $\sin\pi=0$ but $\sin x\ne 0$ for any $x\in (0,\pi)$. But other ways of developing the theory of $\cos$ and $\sin$ exist: you need to be explicit where you are starting out from to answer your question.]

Comment: @0xbadf00d It will not let me see the book, so I cannot tell whether it is a typo or an unfortunate choice of notation. However, I heavily doubt that they have defined $\pi$ differently. I have only seen the common definition of $\pi$ in the recent literature.

Answer (score 1):

Let $z=x+iy$ where $x,y\in\Bbb{R}$. Then, $e^z=e^xe^{iy}$ belongs to $\Bbb{R}$ if and only if $e^{iy}\in\Bbb{R}$ (because $\Bbb{R}$ is a field and $e^x\in\Bbb{R}$), which happens if and only if $y\in \pi\Bbb{Z}$. Therefore, $e^{z}\in\Bbb{R}$ if and only if $z\in \Bbb{R}+i\pi\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: You haven't proved anything, just asserted that the result is true.

Comment: @ancient mathematician sure, I haven't given a detailed proof. The non-trivial part being that $e^{iy}$ is real if and only if $y$ is an integer multiple of $\pi$. The level of difficulty in proving this depends of course on the definition adopted for $\pi$, but this is something treated in literally any complex analysis book. Also, given the level of questions OP has asked previously (eg Banach spaces, functional analysis, PDEs etc etc) I would have expected that merely a mention of this 'fundamental' property of the exponential is sufficient to remind OP.

Comment: Otherwise, fine I'd be happy to delete the answer and merely point to OP that this is a basic complex analysis fact which can for example be found in Ahlfors' text, in the section on exponential functions and its periodicity (because clearly it doesn't make sense for anyone to reproduce a proof of a basic fact which is readily available in a textbook).

Comment: Thanks, your comments clarify how to read your answer.